# Proving the number of leaves is larger by at least two than the number of vertices with a degree of at least 3

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

> Prove that in every tree, the number of leaves is larger by at least two than the number of vertices with a degree of at least 3.

Trying induction, I get something that is too short to be right, and I don't see how to use $\sum d(v)=2(n-1)$ because we have to prove here that $\displaystyle\sum_{d(v)=1}1 \ge \sum_{d(v)\ge 3}1+2 $ and there's no accounting here for the $d(v)=2$.

Another thing I noticed is that every vertex in a tree such that $d(v) > 1$ leads to an amount $> 1$ of leaves. So for every single $d(v)=3$ there will be at least two leaves. But can I prove that? any hints?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722628/let-g-be-a-tree-and-let-k-be-the-number-of-vertices-in-g-whose-degree-is-at-l/1723831#1723831 Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoting the # of vertices with degree $i$ as $X_i$, we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot X_i = 2(n-1) \tag{1}
$$
where $k$ is the largest degree.

Moreover, we also have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k X_i = n \tag{2}
$$

Thus, computing $2 \cdot (2)-(1)$ leads to
\begin{align}
&X_1 + \sum_{i=3}^k (2-i)\cdot X_i = 2 \\
\Rightarrow &X_1 = \sum_{i=3}^k (i-2)\cdot X_i + 2 \geq \sum_{i=3}^k X_i + 2
\end{align}

Remind that $X_1$ is the # of leaves. We thus have proved the argument.

Comment: How is $2\cdot (2) - (1)$ leads to this? I see the $(2-i)x_i$ part but why is it equal to $2$? Also, what about $X_2$?

Comment: @kuhaku $2 \cdot (2) - (1) = 2 \cdot n - 2 \cdot(n-1) = 2$. Moreover, \begin{align} & 2\cdot (2) - (1) \\ = & \sum_{i=1}^k 2\cdot X_i - \sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot X_i \\ = & \sum_{i=1}^k (2 - i) \cdot X_i \end{align}. For $i=2$, $i - 2 = 0$, so $X_2$ vanishes.

Comment: I see. Why does it work or how did you know to do $2(2)-1$?

Comment: @kuhaku Using the noations $X_i$, we want to prove that $$X_1 \geq X_3 + \cdots + X_k + 2$$ You can observe from the inequality that the term $X_2$ doesn't exist. So we should attempt to remove $X_2$ from (1) and (2). Luckily, $2 \cdot (2) - (1)$ does the work well.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Suppose that $v$ is a vertex of degree $2$ connected to vertices $u$ and $w$; if you remove $v$ and join $u$ and $w$ by an edge, you don’t change the degree of any of the remaining vertices, and you still have a tree. Repeat this process until you have no vertices of degree $2$. Now let $\ell$ be the number of leaves and express $\sum_v\deg v$ for the reduced tree in two different ways.

Comment: So we have: $\displaystyle\sum_{d(v)\ge 3}d(v)=2n-2-l$? I don't see how to turn this into an inequality..

Comment: @kuhaku: You have $\sum_v\deg v\ge\ell+3(n-\ell)$.

Comment: Ah, I see why $\sum d(v)\ge 3n +l$ but why the $-3l$?

Comment: @kuhaku: $n$ is the total number of vertices, so $n-\ell$ is the number of non-leaves. Those are the vertices with degree $\ge 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Induction is the way, but in a more simple way:

If you remove a leaf from the tree, it is still a tree, and you have three cases

1 - the father of the leaf you removed is now a leaf, so the number of leaves and nodes with degree $\ge$3 are both the same

2 - the father of the leaf you removed had exactly degree 3, so now it has degree 2, and the number of leaves and nodes with degree $\ge$3 both decreased by one

3 - the father of the leaf you removed had degree $
>$3, so now it has degree $\ge$3, and the number of leaves has decreased by one, and nodes with degree $\ge$3  remained the same

In each case, the induction works