# Let G be a tree, and let $k$ be the number of vertices in G whose degree is at least 3. Prove that G has at least $k+2$ leaves.

Tags: graph-theory

I assume that I need to use the theorem that states that the sum of the degrees of the vertices is equal to twice the number of edges. Then, because $k$ must be greater than or equal to 3, the there must be 1.5 edges, but that is impossible. How else can I continue this proof, using the stated theorem?

Comment: Do it by induction on the total number of vertices in the tree; it's true for trees with 3 vertices by checking cases (in fact it's false for $n < 3$ depending on your definition of a leaf).  How do you go from trees with $n$ vertices to trees with $n+1$ vertices?

The method you're talking about will also work, though.

Comment: What is F? And just because there are k vertices with degree $\ge 3$, why does that mean that k has to be $\ge 3$ ?

Comment: The above comment is correct in that there is no reason that $k \geq 3$, and I'm assuming here that $F = G$.  But the induction will still work.

Comment: OP, do you understand the induction argument?  If so, please up-vote the help you receive!  If not I can post a full solution.

Comment: @JohnSamples Can you please post a full solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are $n$ vertices and $l$ leaves. Then there are $n - k - l$ vertices of degree 2. So the sum of the degrees of vertices is at least $3k + 2(n - k - l) + l$, which simplifies to $k + 2n - l$.

Using the theorem you mention,
$$
2n - 2 ≥ k + 2n - l
$$
so
$$
l ≥ k + 2.
$$

Comment: Could you please explain how you got $3k+2(n−k−l)+l$ degrees of vertices? I am slightly confused about this...

Comment: There are $l$ vertices of degree 1--adding up their degrees gives $l$. There are $(n-k-l)$ vertices of degree 2; adding up their degrees gives $2(n-k-l)$. There are $k$ vertices of degree at least 3; adding up their degrees gives at least $3k$.

Comment: For $2n−2≥k+2n−l$, how did you get the $2n-2$ rather than just $2n$? Shouldn't it be that the sum of the degrees of the vertices is equal to **twice** the number of edges? @Kundor

Comment: @DiscreteMath: In any tree with $n$ vertices, there are $n - 1$ edges.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you made a typo and what you call F in the statement is actually G, then via Induction on the total number of vertices of the graph (let's call this $n$):

Note: You will need the fact that every tree on 3 or more vertices has at least 2 leaves, this is easily proven if you have never seen it before

Base case: $n = 3$

For a tree on 3 vertices, there are no vertices of degree 3, so $k = 0$ and so the result holds as the tree has 2 leaves

Assume the result holds for any tree on $r < n$ vertices,

Consider now a tree $G$ on $n$ vertices such that the number of vertices of degree 3 is $k$, since $G$ is a tree then it has at least 2 leaves, pick one of them and call it $v$

Consider now the graph $G - \{v\}$ obtained by removing $v$ and the edge incident to it from $G$

This new graph is a tree on $n - 1$ vertices, and the number of vertices of degree 3 is $k$ (as we have only removed a vertex of degree 1), so by induction, $G - \{v\}$ has at least $k + 2$ leaves

Thus we see that $G$ itself has at least $k + 2$ leaves (as the number of leaves of $G \geq G - \{v\}$)

Answer (score 1):

There is already a solid solution, but at OP's request here is an induction argument (IMO the simplest argument).

Every tree on $n+1$ vertices is a tree on $n$ vertices with a leaf attached.  So take an arbitrary tree on $n$ vertices and by induction assume the result holds for this tree.

Attach a leaf.  If you attach it to a vertex with degree one you create 0 new leaves and 0 new vertices of degree higher than $3$, leaving the inequality satisfied.

If you attach it to a vertex of degree two, you create one new leaf and one new vertex of degree 3, leaving the inequality satisfied.

If you attach it to a vertex of degree three or higher you create one new leaf and no new vertices of degree three or higher, so you satisfy the inequality even more strongly.